# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88980406)

Tags: wpf

We have a WPF application that's connected to a microscope.
There is a scenario where in the application we can switch the microscope's objective lens and when we do that there is a hardware call that tells the microscope to change the lens and after that the UI is updated.

We ran a stress test on this scenario and eventually got a

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88980406)
```

with source as `PresentationCore.dll`

The call stack is:

```
Message = Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980406;Category: Critical;Priority: -1;EventId: 1;
Timestamp: Wednesday, April 13, 2011 6:35:46 PM;Message: FullText = System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x88980406): Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980406
at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()
at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.CompositionTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(ResourceHandle hCompositionTarget, RECT windowRect, Color colorKey, Single constantAlpha, MILWindowLayerType windowLayerType, MILTransparencyFlags transparencyMode, Boolean isChild, Boolean isRTL, Boolean renderingEnabled, Int32 disableCookie, Channel channel)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean enableRenderTarget, Nullable``1 channelSet)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowSettings(Boolean enableRenderTarget)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.SetWindowPos(HandleRef hWnd, HandleRef hWndInsertAfter, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 cx, Int32 cy, Int32 flags)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.Resize(Size newSize)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnLayoutUpdated(Object obj, EventArgs args)
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.PopupSecurityHelper.SetWindowRootVisual(Visual v)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.SetRootVisualToPopupRoot()
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateWindow(Boolean asyncCall)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.SetBinding(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty dp, BindingBase binding)
at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.CreateRootPopup(Popup popup, UIElement child)
at System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip.HookupParentPopup()
at System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip.OnIsOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Boolean value)
at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.RaiseToolTipOpeningEvent()
at System.Windows.Controls.PopupControlService.OnRaiseToolTipOpeningEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick(Object unused)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
at System.Windows.Application.Run()
```

The machine Configuration is:
Microsoft Vista SP2 .Net Framework 3.5

Can you please provide us some inputs on how to resolve this.

Comment: No, unfortunately, we can't, because *you* are not providing the full exception details.

Comment: Happens also on my .NetFramework 4.0 Project which using Interop.HwndTarget. exception apears on resize.

Comment: @BerndOtt, you just saved my ass, I love you.

Comment: @Tsury btw. i can also crash my app with highdpi settings. I will try in a free minute to switch to software rendering. thx to you, too.

Comment: @BerndOtt, what methods do you use to change the DPI? I suspect my project changes it as well.

Comment: @Tsury user does it themself in the windows screen dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

As BerndOtt suggested, at least for me, this had something to do with a HwndTarget getting resized.

I commented out these two lines of code, and this issue is now resolved for me:

```
HwndTarget hwndTarget = source.CompositionTarget;
hwndTarget.RenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

Put it in the onLoaded method, as demonstrated [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/janiv/2009/06/07/hardware-acceleration-in-wpf/).

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a shot and hopefully it will resolve the problem. My problem is I'm loading my WPF screen through an xbap to load the screen inside IE. It's also using different components, hosted in a winForms base. So it can any of the WPF controls hosted on this base, and the strange thing is its only when the Xbap closes that this error occurs, after a recent windows Update